# Why only half of expected output using texture coordinate wrapping modes, example from SB OpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

wrap.py from Superbible OpenGL is rendering only half the expected output.  Note the two images.  What could be wrong in the source code as it seems ok, there should be the four textures, why are the two missing?  Thanks.

Actual results that I'm receiving now same as expected results.

[image: expected results]

Update: Thanks to Rabbid76 for the solution code to this program.

dependency files: [rightarrows.ktx](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/rightarrows.ktx) , [ktxloader.py](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/shared/ktxloader.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
#import time

sys.path.append("./shared")

#from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader
from ktxloader import KTXObject    # location of ktx file format loader

#from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44

fullscreen = True

#import numpy.matlib
#import numpy as np

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()


texture = GLuint(0)
program = GLuint(0)
vao = GLuint(0)


class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global texture
        global program
        global vao

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        vs = GLuint(0)
        fs = GLuint(0)

        vs_source = '''
#version 410 core

uniform vec2 offset;

out vec2 tex_coord;

void main(void)
{
    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4(-0.45, -0.45, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4( 0.45, -0.45, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4(-0.45,  0.45, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4( 0.45,  0.45, 0.5, 1.0));

    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + vec4(offset, 0.0, 0.0);
    tex_coord = vertices[gl_VertexID].xy * 3.0 + vec2(0.45 * 3);
}
'''

        fs_source = '''
#version 410 core

uniform sampler2D s;

out vec4 color;

in vec2 tex_coord;

void main(void)
{
    color = texture(s, tex_coord);
}
'''


        #// Generate a name for the texture
        glGenTextures(1, texture)

        #// Load texture from file
        ktxobj = KTXObject()
        texture = ktxobj.ktx_load("rightarrows.ktx")

        #// Now bind it to the context using the GL_TEXTURE_2D binding point
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vs, vs_source)
        glCompileShader(vs)

        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fs, fs_source)
        glCompileShader(fs)

        program = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(program, vs)
        glAttachShader(program, fs)
        glLinkProgram(program)

        glDeleteShader(vs)
        glDeleteShader(fs)

        glGetProgramInfoLog(program)

        glGenVertexArrays(1, vao)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)


    def display(self):

        #currentTime = time.time()

        green = [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        yellow = [ 0.4, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);

        wrapmodes = [ GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_REPEAT, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT ]
        offsets = [  [-0.5, -0.5],
                      [0.5, -0.5],
                     [-0.5,  0.5],
                      [0.5,  0.5] ]

        glUseProgram(program)
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, yellow)

        for i in range(0, 4):

            glUniform2fv(0, 1, offsets[i])
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapmodes[i])
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapmodes[i])

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)


        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Texture Wrap Modes')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Ported from c++ source: [wrapmodes.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is:

> ```
> glUniform2fv(0, 1, offsets[i*2])
> ```

`offset` is a one dimensional array.

So `offsets[i*2]` is a single element from the array.

If you want to set 2 consecutive values form the array to `uniform vec2 offset;`, then you've to do:

```py
glUniform2f(0, offsets[i*2], offsets[i*2+1])
```

or

```py
glUniform2fv(0, 1, offsets[i*2:i*2+2])
```

or you've to turn `offsets` to a 2 dimensional array:

```py
offsets = [[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]]
```

```py
glUniform2fv(0, 1, offsets[i])
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, Thank You!